Figuring out the difference between cv::imread / cv::dnn::blobFromImage and QImage
I have the following image loading code (example: to feed YOLO recognition algorithm) which works:
cv::Mat image = imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(
  image,
  1 / 255.0,
  cv::Size(640, 640),
  cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0),
  false,
  false
);

float* input_tensor_values = (float*)blob.data;
process_image(input_tensor_values);

That said, this image loading code is the only reason I need OpenCV in my app which is a bit of a heavy-handed dependency for something that is only reading and scaling an image, considering that my app is using Qt which should be able to handle this task.
But, I am not able to load with Qt's QImage the image in a format that matches the layout output by cv::dnn::blobFromImage.
I tried:
QImage img(image_path);
img = img.scaled(640, 640,
    Qt::AspectRatioMode::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
    Qt::SmoothTransformation);
img = img.copy(0, 0, 640, 640);
img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_BGR888); // Also tried RGB24

// At this point, img.bits() has the same pixel values than the
// content of cv::Mat image if I'm loading a 640x640 image.

// Then, I rescale: 
auto src = img.constBits();
float* input_tensor_values = /* some storage */;
for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 640 * 640;) {
  input_tensor_values[i + 0] = (float(src[0]) / 255.f);
  input_tensor_values[i + 1] = (float(src[1]) / 255.f);
  input_tensor_values[i + 2] = (float(src[2]) / 255.f);

  // clang-format on
  i += 3;
  src += 3;
}

process_image(input_tensor_values);

but when I compare the values I get here, they don't match the values output by  cv::dnn::blobFromImage: for instance, if I print the first twelve values of the  input_tensor_values array in both case, I see :
// first column is the pixel value before scaling, second is after scaling
qt: 135 0.529412
qt: 151 0.592157
qt: 158 0.619608
qt: 135 0.529412
qt: 151 0.592157
qt: 158 0.619608
qt: 139 0.545098
qt: 150 0.588235
qt: 158 0.619608
qt: 139 0.545098
qt: 150 0.588235
qt: 158 0.619608

// first column is the pixel value before blobFromImage, second is after blobFromImage
cv: 135 0.529412
cv: 151 0.529412
cv: 158 0.545098
cv: 135 0.545098
cv: 151 0.537255
cv: 158 0.533333
cv: 139 0.541176
cv: 150 0.533333
cv: 158 0.533333
cv: 139 0.521569
cv: 150 0.52549 
cv: 158 0.529412

as one can see, cv::dnn::blobFromImage is definitely not only doing scaling, but entirely reshuffling the data in mysterious ways.
What's the actual storage? From the values it seems that OpenCV may be laying out the channels in a planar way, e.g. RRRRRRRRRRRR...GGGGGGG...BBBBBBBBBB... instead of RGBRGBRGB ? This does not makes too much sense to me as the models I'm using state that they need RGB or sometimes BGR images as input, yet this is neither a standard RGB or BGR format (yet this seems to work).

"NCHW order" --- if multiple images, the images are the first order, channels (R,G,B or such) second order, then rows and columns (standard grayscale row-major order image). So, a sequence of colour planes repeated as many times as many images it represents.

why would the models say that their input is in RGB format then ? this is definitely not RGB. This seems to be the correct answer though so if you post it I'll accept it.

RGB as opposed to BGR or other color spaces like YUV. order of dimensions doesn't affect that. order of dimensions is given as NCHW or NHWC. CHW is common in neural networks.
